# Power steering noise that goes away

Tags: bmw, power-steering

My e46 M3 is making the tell-tale whining and groaning of a power steering pump that is either out of PS oil, or gasping it's last breath.  The oil level is fine, so I immediately jumped to the conclusion that the pump is bad. The thing that gives me pause is that the noise goes away after a few minutes, which seems odd. Do PS noises like this normally go away? The steering feels totally normal, still.

Also, I have read that a collapsed return line (to the pump) from PS rack could cause the same symptoms. Will a collapsed hose be obvious from a visual inspection? How do I differentiate between a collapsed hose and a bad pump?

Thanks, Jeremy

Comment: Odd, my E60 M5 does the same thing.  I would check the return line for any kinks.  Are you leaking any fluid? Have you tried bleeding the ps system to see if there is any air in the system?

Comment: PS pumps are self-bleeding, so I can't imagine the issue is being caused by air in the lines. Also, I don't see any leaks on the garage floor, so that doesn't seem like it would be the cause.

Comment: Do you have a combo/serpentine belt, or a dedicated PS belt, and if a dedicated one, are you positive it's not belt slippage? Hmm, okay, just realized it's a BMW, going to guess serpentine and that the belt probably isn't the problem...

Comment: Now, in 2017, the noise is the same and the power steering system still works fine. I guess it's normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My power-steering pump failed about 2 months after the noise you described. I'm in an E46 3 Series. The noise would be louder when turning at a slower speed than it would at a higher speed. Dealer labour and part came to $1600 CAD, warranty saved me there.

Answer (score 5):

A lot of BMWs have a noise, but it might be a pump going bad. If I remember right, the lines are right under the reservoir. Check them for softness, and if they are soft/chewy I guess you can replace them. If it's a pump, run until it pops, as they are like $400. As far as the lines from the rack, those are hard lines, and unless clearly pinched not sure if you can see anything.

Comment: chewy is a gross image for a power steering line yet also absolutely perfect.  Well done!  ;-)

Comment: @Bob Thanks. I do try to give the best description for the condition =-)

Comment: *Chewy* hoses? ;)